# Core Data saving race condition bug

Tags: multithreading, ios, core-data, concurrency

I have an `NSOperation` which updates the apps data. This operation has its own context and changes are passed back to the context on the main thread via the `contextDidSave` notification.

The update operation deletes objects. These deletions are inadvertently causing a crash. The crash occurs when the main thread is reloading a `UITableView` at the same time that the update context is saving. The datasource for the tableview is backed by a `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Neither CoreData or UIKit output any logging. The crash is a SIG_ABRT that occurs in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` while accessing an attribute of managedObject. Here's the result of a successful update. You can see that the table is populate once, then the context saves, which in turn causes the table to be reloaded:

```
tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: rowCount = 29
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 0
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 1
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 2
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 3
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 4
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 5
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 6
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 7
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 8
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 9
Will saved update context
Did saved update context
Will merge update context
tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: rowCount = 58
Did merge update context
tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: rowCount = 29
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 0
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 1
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 2
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 3
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 4
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 5
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 6
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 7
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 8
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 9
```

And here's an the output when a crash occurred:

```
tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: rowCount = 29
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 0
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 1
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 2
Will saved update context
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 3
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 4
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: row: 5
```

[image: stacktrace]

I can think of two potential solutions:

1. lock the `persitentStoreCoordinator` while the table view is refreshing. (This could be done by subclassing `UITableView` and overriding `reloadData` to provide a location to lock and unlock the store)
2. Defer the deletion to a later date, eg, when the app quits. (This could be done by adding a `isStale` attrib to the entities or by creating a new `Trash` entity and adding objects to that.)

However, both of these solutions seem really hacky. Am I missing something? My first though was to try and make the `NSFetchedResultsController` pre fetch all objects, but this isn't possible. Another possible solution was to lock the store when using `controllerDidChangeContent:` but the problem still occurs when the table reload is not triggered by the fetchedResultsController.

Comment: @Benedict Cohen what does the crash show on the console and stacktrace?

Comment: Are you sure you're doing it right? "This operation has its own context and changes are passed back to the context on the main thread via the contextDidSave notification." This part looks especially dodgy http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html

Comment: @TheBlack I've double checked and I'm 99% certain I'm doing it right. I've read and re-read Track Changes in Other Threads Using Notifications and the docs for mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW5

Comment: @Benedict Cohen Have you seen CoreDataBooks example? Seems there are couple of gotchas one could easily forget or miss..  Also, do you use beginUpdate/endUpdate in table view?

Comment: @Benedict Cohen SIG_ABRT can also suggest releasing objects too soon. Is it possible some other object holds reference to deleted object or deleted object to some invalid reference to object? From what I've seen, you should get internalinconsistency exception if context merge failed, rather than SIG_ABRT (I'm not 100% sure but it's worth to check)

Comment: @TheBlack The problem occurs prior to the contexts being merged - it occurs when a contexts on a different thread is saved. I've had a quick look at the CoreDataBooks example. CoreDataBooks is single-threaded so doesn't shed light on this problem. I've filed a bug report with Apple. I think the problem is due to deferred fetching of NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: @Benedict Cohen One more suggestion and I wont bother you again :) How are you allocating context in NSOperation?

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned the stack trace is vital.  Without we can only guess at the solution.